# C++ Splitting the input problem

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, strtok

I am being given input in the form of:

```
(8,7,15)
(0,0,1) (0,3,2) (0,6,3)
(1,0,4) (1,1,5)
(2,1,6) (2,2,7) (2,5,8)
(3,0,9) (3,3,10) (3,4,11) (3,5,12)
(4,1,13) (4,4,14)
(7,6,15)
```

where I have to remember the amount of triples there are. I wrote a quick testing program to try read the input from `cin` and then split string up to get the numbers out of the input. The program doesn't seem to read all the lines, it stops after `(1,1,5)` and prints out a random `7` afterwards

I created this quick testing function for one of the functions I am trying to create for my assignment:

```
int main ()
{
  string line;
  char * parse;

  while (getline(cin, line)) {

    char * writable = new char[line.size() + 1];
    copy (line.begin(), line.end(), writable);
    parse = strtok (writable," (,)");

    while (parse != NULL)
    {
      cout << parse << endl;
      parse = strtok (NULL," (,)");
      cout << parse << endl;
      parse = strtok (NULL," (,)");
      cout << parse << endl;
      parse = strtok (NULL," (,)");
    }

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me fix my code or give me a working sample?

Comment: Have you tried running it under a debugger to find the exact line where it segfaults?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://ideone.com/k9ZAb

Comment: @kay it does not seg fault anymore, but there is still a problem here that is making my output incorrect

Comment: All you have to do is count the triples? If you know that's the only format there is (i.e. there's not going to be anything but triples in that file) then you can just count the opening parentheses `(`

Comment: @seth I need to count the triples and use the numbers

Comment: Needs more error handling also. What if I provide an input like "(1,2,3,4)"? You need to deal with user errors, especially when parsing files. Optionally, make your parsing more dynamic (allow for spaces before and (at least) after the commas). Since this is an "assignment" as stated in the text, that'll probably raise your mark once you get it working. As for your actual problem, I'm working on it now.

Comment: Also make sure you `delete[] writable` when you don't need it (and `parse`) anymore. Currently, at the end of the outer while-loop.

Comment: I know I'm being knit-picky, but you can just convert a string to a char * with the c_str() method of string. Less bug prone.

Comment: @JackMc: `strtok` modifies the string it's passed, so you can't use `c_str()` here. I think a bigger problem is that `writable` is not zero-terminated.

Comment: @JackMC I don't have to worry about the error handling, we can assume the user inputs correct information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this simple function:

```
istream& read3(int& a, int& b, int& c, istream& stream = cin) {
    stream.ignore(INT_MAX, '(');
    stream >> a;
    stream.ignore(INT_MAX, ',');
    stream >> b;
    stream.ignore(INT_MAX, ',');
    stream >> c;
    stream.ignore(INT_MAX, ')');

    return stream;
 }
```

It expects the stream to start at a `(`, so it skips any characters and stops after the first `(` it sees. It reads in an `int` into `a` which is passed by reference (so the outside `a` is affected by this) and then reads up to and skips the first comma it sees. Wash, rinse, repeat. Then after reading the third `int` in, it skips the closing `)`, so it is ready to do it again.

It also returns an `istream&` which has `operator bool` overloaded to return `false` when the stream is at its end, which is what breaks the `while` loop in the example.

You use it like this:

```
// don't forget the appropriate headers...
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int a, b, c;

while (read3(a, b, c)) {
    cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << endl;
}
```

That prints:

```
8 7 15
0 0 1
0 3 2
0 6 3
1 0 4
1 1 5
2 1 6
2 2 7
2 5 8
3 0 9
3 3 10
3 4 11
3 5 12
4 1 13
4 4 14
7 6 15
```

When you give it your input.

Because this is an assignment, I leave it to you to add error handling, etc.

Comment: @snpn you could do that many ways. One way would be to use std::getline to read a line and count the # of (, then wrap the line in a stringstream and do the read3 on that.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a blog 9 days back exactly to parse such inputs:

- [Playing around with Boost.Spirit - Parsing integer triplets](http://stackoverview.blogspot.com/2011/08/playing-around-with-boostspirit-parsing.html)

And you can see the output here for your input : http://ideone.com/qr4DA