# Formatted reading a file data C++

Tags: c++, stl

I have data in the following format in a file
`( p1, p2 ) (p3, p4 ) ( p5, p6 )`

How do i read this in C++, I can read a line and parse it , but I was looking for some `C++ stl` way to read this kind of format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Splitting the input problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238700/c-splitting-the-input-problem)

Comment: Maybe off-topic, but... Have you thought about using Boost.Regex? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the format you want to represent the data in your program. One way is to have a `struct` with a custom stream-extraction operator:

```
struct Data {
    int val1; // just assuming int for the data-type
    int val2;
};

std::istream & operator>>(std::istream& input, Data & obj) {
    input.ignore(2, '('); // skip all including opening brace
    input >> obj.val1;
    input.ignore(2, ','); // skip comma
    input >> obj.val2;
    input.ignore(2, ')'); // skip closing brace
    return input;
}
```

As @Seth Carnegie demonstrates in an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7238896/160206), you can also use `INT_MAX` to make sure you skip enough - however, using `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` would be even better.

Then you can read all the contents of the file like this:

```
std::vector<Data> all_data;
std::ifstream input_file("your_file.txt");
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Data>(input_file), 
          std::istream_iterator<Data>(),
          std::back_inserter(all_data));
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/kZxZx) is a complete working example.

Comment: Using stream oriented operations is a good advice imho. But won't the suggested implementation also accept *incorrect* input like: `[ 42 : 42 }` ?

Comment: don't you mean `INT_MAX` instead of `MAX_INT`?

Comment: @ereOn: Yes, it will. It assumes that the input is well-formed. Adding error-checking there makes it much more complex.

Comment: this does not work on windows. I tried your example on windows and does not work. Although work on Unix.

Comment: On linux your example work and gives me output, but on windows I am not getting anything.